# PHP Cant Pass Variable include File?

Tags: php

Lets go to the Point,

I hava a form like this

**exhibition.php**

```
<?php
    include("email_class.php");
if(isset($_POST[SAVE])){

   $email = $_POST[EMAIL];
   $company = $_POST[COMPANY];
   $gender  = $_POST[GENDER];
   $buyer   = $_POST[BUYER];
 $discussion = $_POST[DISCUSSION]; 

   $class = new email_class();

    $class->notifikasi($discussion);



}//end if
 ?>
```

And the code include file like this

**email_class.php**

```
<?php

class email_class{

   function notifikasi($discussion){

       if($discussion == "DISCUSSION"){


        $to  = $email;      
        $subjek = "Thanks for visiting us at Gulfood exhibition, Dubai";
        $message = "<html>
        <head>
            <title>Exibithion Email</title>
        </head>


        <body>
          bla blaa";

$message.= "Dear <b> ".$gender." ".$buyer."</b><br><br>";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";

    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'From: **** Group <export@***>' . "\r\n";

echo $message;

     }//end if    





   }//end function


}//end of class



?>
```

Ok, echo HTML mail is Succees. anything is running well, only the variabel from exhibition.php cant pass to the email_class.php.

Can anyone Fix my Problem?

Comment: You are calling `include("email_class.php");` before your variables in `exhibition.php` file are defined

Comment: can you more specifict? im still not understand

Comment: When you call the email_class.php file (its in your first line) you haven't defined yet any of your varibles(since they are after that line and not before), so you need to call `include("email_class.php");` after you define your varibles.

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez I have change the position of include after define the variabel and still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the values as arguments to `notifikasi`.

```
 <?php
     include("email_class.php");
     if(isset($_POST[SAVE])){

           $class = new email_class();

           $class->notifikasi($_POST[EMAIL], $_POST[COMPANY], $_POST[GENDER], $_POST[BUYER], $_POST[DISCUSSION])

    }//end if
 ?>
```

**class**

```
class email_class{

   function notifikasi($email, $company, $gender, $buyer, $discussion){

       if($discussion == "DISCUSSION"){
 /** ... **/
```

Comment: I know this Answer, but I think, after I have include some file to another file, variable on first file automatically include. If I use this methode, I must include all of the variabel

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean at the end. But if you'are using a class, it's better to use local variables, the other way was a little hard to follow, when you have a bigger project, you'll go nuts.

Comment: OK thanks for your answer